# centering menu text in wordpress in header.php

Tags: css, wordpress, center

here's my website http://www.saraandcompany.ca/

I would like the navigation under the image to also be centred.

I've tried all sorts of ways of doing it but I have no idea how.

here's the header.php file.

```
        <center><img src="http://www.saraandcompany.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/weblogo.png" style="PADDING-BOTTOM:15px"></center>

    <h1 id="main-title"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>

    <nav>
        <?php $args = array(
            'show_home'   => Work,
            'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title'
            ); ?>
        <?php wp_page_menu( $args ); ?> 
    </nav>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</header>
```

thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change a few lines in the CSS:

```
nav {
  float: right; /* Remove */
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block; /* Keep */
  margin-left: 20px; /* Remove */
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 20px; /* Remove */
  margin: 0 10px; /* Add */
}
```

Comment: None of that information is in the text given. Is it somewhere else in the theme files?

Comment: Indeed, it's in this file: http://www.saraandcompany.ca/wp-content/themes/simpleportfoliotheme/style.css